# AppInsights > Logs > Render Bar Chart to start from 0

Tags: azure-application-insights

In my angular application I am tracking filters that users utilize on one of the pages. What I can later see in Logs, is the following (query for last 24 hours)

[image]

What I am interested in, is the count of filters groupped by its name. So I created the following query:

[image]

However the problem as you can see, is that my y-axis starts from 1 instead of 0. To users this looks like the last two filters don't have any values, where in reality they both have count of 1.

I have tried to use ymin=0 together with render function, however it did not work (chart still starts from 1). Then I have read I need to use `make-series()` function and so I tried:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp >= ago(24h) 
| where customDimensions.pageName == 'product'
| make-series Count=count(name) default=0 on timestamp from datetime(2019-10-10) to datetime(2019-10-11) step 1d by name
| project name, Count
```

However the result is some weird matrix instead of a regular table:
[image]

I have just started with application insights thus any help in respect to this matter would be more than appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but the correct syntax to pass in ymin and ymax when using a query is this:

```
| ...
| render barchart with (ymin=0, ymax=100)
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuremonitor

Answer (score 1):

in Workbooks in application insights you could do *almost* this query (see below for a simplification?), then use the chart settings and set the axis min/max explicitly:

[image: chart settings]

but why are you using make-series but then summarizing to just one series?

in this specific case is `summarize` simpler:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp between(datetime(2019-10-10) .. datetime(2019-10-11))
| where customDimensions.pageName == 'product'
| summarize Count=count(name) by name
| render barchart
```

in the logs blade (where you are), you could do this query, and I *believe* you can use

`render barchart title="blah" ymin=0`

(at some point workbooks will be able to "see" all the rendeer options like ymin/ymax/xmin/xmax/title/etc, but right now they're all stripped out at service layer)

Comment: The first solution, using Workbooks worked fine (I was able to set ymin to 0). Unfortunately, when I tried to manually add *ymin=0* to render() function, nothing happened. Is there by any chances way, how to make it work via Logs? If not then I will mark your answer as complete.

Comment: For completeness, I made the render query as following:
**| render barchart with(title='Chart Title', ymin=4)**

Comment: for workbooks, you'd use the chart settings to explicitly set the y min to 0.  (not all of the data sources we support let you put that information in the query text, so our common place to set it is in the chart settings itself)